# How can we measure performance overhead resulting from writing to files or folders?

Tags: logs, performance, benchmark, read-write

I have a tool which takes as input a folder or a file and then it logs operations done on that file or folder (modifying,deletion,creating new folders or files, etc). I was looking for a way to measure the overhead of using such a tool. Any suggestions? Is there any suitable benchmarking tool which can help in this such that it simulates the operations in order to increase the log file size and hence measure the performance?

Comment: If you simply want to get the amount of time not directly running your application code, you can use `time` for this. Disk I/O and other operations are performed by the kernel, thus they show up as sys-time. Time spent in userspace (your application) is user-time. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/556411/486035